# Identity Server (3) -> Add a Terms and Conditions Stage

Tags: identityserver3

We are using IdentityServer3, when a user log's in we need to check if they have accepted the services terms and conditions and this needs to be part of the Auth, what would be the way to implement this?

Is it possible to redirect to a terms page before we complete the login?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

They do have some of this documented (more like hints on how to do it).  From the [IdentityServer3 UserService docs](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html):

> Partial login:  In addition to a full login, the authentication APIs can
>   perform a “partial login”. A partial login allows the user service to
>   interrupt the user’s login workflow and redirect them to a custom page
>   where they must perform some action before they can continue to login
>   (e.g. performing 2fa, completing a registration form, or accepting a
>   EULA).

Basically you will need to have a custom UserService that will override either `AuthenticateLocalAsync` or `AuthenticateExternalAsync` (or both).  In this method you can check to make sure that they have accepted the terms (e.g. by checking your database), and if not, redirect them to a page to get their consent via the authentication context's `AuthenticateResult`.

The [IdentityServer3.Samples CustomUserService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService/CustomUserService) on github has an example implementation.  Here is a snippet with relevant bits:

```
    public override Task AuthenticateLocalAsync(LocalAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var user = Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == context.UserName && x.Password == context.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (user.AcceptedEula)
            {
                context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.Subject, user.Username);
            }
            else
            {
                context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("~/eula", user.Subject, user.Username);
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

The second `AuthenticateResult` is the one that indicates something else needs to be done, as the redirect link is included (`"~/eula"`, which is where you would put your "Terms and Conditions" page with a checkbox).